# Python: How to do a program that can show specific part of its own code?

Tags: python

I can do a program that read its own code using `f=open(sys.argv[0])` and then parse it, but, exist a simple way to do something like this?

```
>>> def f(x): return x*x
...
>>> print(definition_of(f))
"def f(x): return x*x"
```

Thanks!

Comment: Hi! yes, this is a duplicate... I'm very sorry for that, i did a search with no result, but, i didn't with the correct words. Thanks! (no proble if a moderator delete it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the following into a script file:

```
#!/bin/python

import inspect

def f(x):
  return x * x

print inspect.getsource(f)
```